# Forge - Query only specific property

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Is it possible to use the https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/ endpoint to query only a property with a specific name, regardless of its value?

Answer (score 0):

Fom [Documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/):
$prefix: Returns only the objects with their name attribute beginning with the specified string.
The first element of the array contains the name of the attribute to match (name). **The second element contains the string to match**.

Sorry, it's not possible without giving an exact name and value.

Comment: "Returns only the objects where the value of the specified attribute (name attribute or any numerical property) is exactly equal to the specified value."

I would like to retrieve all objects that have property with name X, regardless of the value

Comment: you can use fields, properties.some* please refer to fields object

Comment: Could you give an exemple of the query? The documentation is very hard to understand on how the conditions and fields can be used together

Comment: BTW fields Specifies what properties of the objects to return. Filtering happens in query, but now I realize your requirement is for a wildcard name search, which is currently not possible. sorry.

Comment: not necessarily on the name but more on one of the properties. You can do it with numerical ones but wondering if it's possible to extract all objectIDs that have property X either present or not empty

Comment: on documentation you can refer to properties equals to. BTW there's a new API much more powerful, called AEC Data Model, you can check here for more explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCxqSz2AxNk

Comment: Afaik this only works with Revit 2024 exported model

Comment: yes, that's the pre requisite, but it's very powerful and future proof. I highly recommend you convert your models